# Concatenate Variable Name?

Tags: java, variables, concatenation

Scenario:

- There are two scores. Enemy Score and Player Score.
- The Enemy Score variable is `score0`.
- The Player Score variable is `score1`.
- There is a global variable turn, which holds the value 0 or 1.
- If turn is 0: it's the enemy's turn
- If turn is 1: it's the player's turn
- The scores can only update on a player or enemy turn. Thus 0 and 1 relate to score and turn.

Let's say that Player Score is 5, and on Player's turn, s/he earns 1 point. So I then need to change player's score to 6. Each number is a drawable resource titled n0, n1, n2, n3, etc. (n0-n9)

This works:

So if score=6, and it's Player's turn, then:

```
score1.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("n" + score, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

This works too:

```
if (turn==0) { img = score0; }
else if (turn==1) { img = score1; }
img.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("n" + score, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

But I'd rather have something like this:

```
Image img = "score"+turn
```

Is there a way I can create a variable that is a concatenation of a string and a number to create the variable name I'm trying to access?

**EDIT** / **MOD RECOMMENDATION**: I appreciate that mods are editing for fluidity. Considering this is my first post to stack overflow, and I didn't realize there was a specific format. However, I would suggest that mods not edit out chunks of a paragraph. Especially when a user says she's new to Java. Because the responses people provide will be based on skill level. If the readers assume I'm knowledgeable in Java, they will respond with answers they assume I understand. But if I say "I'm new to this" - it's because I'm looking for an answer in laymans terms. Just food for thought for new mods.

Comment: Why don't you put things in a list or array and make the number the index?

Comment: Use a `Map`. Or a `List`. Or an array. To answer the actual question; yes you can reference a variable with a `String`, but it's complicated and you shouldn't need to until you are much more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

So I just googled a bit more about Map/HashMap, and I think you're right. It might be too complicated for what I'm trying to achieve.

The question still remains unanswered. So it would be nice to have an answer to the topic question for anyone reading this in the future (rather than having "you should do this instead" answers).

The solution that I decided on (for future users with similar issues): was to create a list array and a method to update the score:

```
public void updateScore(int score){
scores.get(turn).setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("n" + score, "drawable", getPackageName())); }
```

[WIP Project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFJr1.png)